# Sencha touch 2 in a W8 application

Tags: cordova, extjs, windows-8, sencha-touch

I have an app developed under iOS and the behavior is correct but I am having a problem with my future implementation under Windows 8 in a tablet, for example messageBox pop-up size is different and I have the message incomplete, this is an example but I have more problems with this implementation, mainly graphic issues. Any clue?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this issue?

Comment: lot of issue you will get in WP8 becuase many css will not work with ie browser, so check your css and change it according to ie. otherwise use win8 default sencha css.. and try

Comment: I am having problems for example with the Ext.MessageBox, text doesn´t appear correctly, I suppose in this case should  I modify the class? How can I do it?, on the other hand if I have problems with only css it is not problem, because I think the mainly issue is with the classes..  what is your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, Sencha Touch inspects the DOM adding the next prefix **".x-ie"**  to the classes or graphic components like buttons for example, with this code added to the specific styles rules you can be able to customize classes or ID´s for our best friend Internet Explorer automatically.